# How to cache an object without user interruption?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, memorycache

This is easier to explain if I first explain my order of events:

1. User requests a webpage that requires x database objects
2. The server checks the cache to see if it is cached, and if it is not, it re-requests the database
3. The page is sent to the user

My issue is, when the user requests a webpage and the cache is expired, it will take a very long time for the cache to update. The reason is because the data that is being cached includes data fetched from other locations, so web requests are being made to update the cache. Because it is making web requests, it can take quite a while for the cache to update, causing the user's webpage to sit there and load for upwards of ten seconds or more.

My question is, how would I go about reducing or completely removing these edge cases where, when the cache is updating, the user's webpage takes forever to load?

The first solution I came up with was to see if I could persist the MemoryCache past its expiration time, or at the very least check its expiration time, so that I can fetch the old object and return that to the user, and then initiate a cache update in another thread for the next user. However, I found that MemoryCache completely removes the items entirely upon expiration (which makes sense), and that there is no way to avoid doing this. I looked into using `CacheItemPriority.NeverRemove`, but there is no way to check the expiration time (for some weird reason).

So the second solution I came up with was to create my own cache, but I don't know how I would go about doing that. The object I am storing is a list objects, so I would prefer to avoid a wrapper object around them (but, if that's what I have to do, I'll be willing to do that). I would like this cache to be abstract, of course, so it can handle any type of item, and using a wrapper object for lists would not allow me to do that.

So what I'm looking for in a custom cache is:

- Ability to check expiration date
- Items are not removed upon expiration so that I can manually update them

Yet through the past couple of hours searching online, I have found nothing that describes a cache that's even remotely close to being able to do something like this (at least, one that's provided with .NET Core or available in the NuGet packages). I have also not found a guide or any examples that would help me understand how to create a custom cache like this.

How would I go abouts making this custom cache? Or is a cache even what I'm looking for here?

Comment: Why not use Redis for caching?  Also you could create an antonymous service that checks the cache at regular intervals and then updates/refreshes the cache.   You may still have edge cases though.  

Real question is why aren't you storing the data in a database in the same region?  Unless it's fast changing data (bitcoin prices, stocks, etc)

Comment: This is a Minecraft website and I am using Crafatar for user avatars. I also have to request Mojang for quite a bit of user account information

Comment: It's unlikely that most of that will change frequently so why not just grab the information and store it in a database under your control?  In all honestly it seems like you're over complicating your project.

Comment: Avatars do change frequently, as well as the Mojang account user information. Appending to the database is not an option here, I am extracting information from the plugins already provided in my database to get what I need to then fetch the data from Crafatar and Mojang's servers. The best solution for me is to cache the results of this into one compiled class that I create. All I need is a cache in which I can extract the data one last time to then update it. I think I've decided I will just instead store this in its own class and variable, and then check that variable.